# Probability by throwing a tetrahedron

Tags: probability

Tetrahedron whose sides are numbered from 1-4, is thrown twice.

If, A - down sides give the same number after throwing it twice.
B - the sum of the down sides is >5

Then determinate, P(A/B) and P(B/A).

Answer (score 1):

You have 16 equally likely combinations: $$(1,1), (2,1), (3,1), (4,1), (2,1), (2,2), (2,3), (2,4), (3,1), (3,2), (3,3), (3,4), (4,1), (4,2), (4,3), (4,4)$$

Do you see which of these are counted by category $A$, which by $B$, and which by $A\cap B$? Find the probability of each of these, and then $P(A/B)$ and $P(B/A)$ can be calculated relatively easily.

Comment: Ok, well, the B contains the following (2,4),(3,3),(3,4),(4,2),(4,3),(4,4). I'm not sure about A? Does it contain all of them?

Comment: $A$ contains the ones where you got *the same number twice*. $(1,1)$ does this, since that means you got a one on the bottom both times. $(1,2)$ doesn't, since you didn't get the same number on both throws.

Comment: Hm.. I understood it as if the numbers of throwing the first time are the same as the ones when the tetrahedron is thrown the second time. But if it's really that, then it shall be 4 - (1,1),(2,2),(3,3),(4,4). That makes it P(A∩B) = 1/2. P(B)=4/16 = 1/4. So, P(A/B) = (1/2)/(1/4) = 1/2?

Comment: $P(A\cap B)$ is the fraction of them that count as examples of both condition $A$ and $B$. The only ones satisfying this are $(3,3)$ and $(4,4)$, giving a probability of $2/16=1/8$. Keep in mind that since this is *more* restrictive than requiring $A$ or $B$ by themselves, $P(A\cap B)$ can't be larger than $P(A)$ or $P(B)$. The logic for $P(A/B)=\frac{P(A\cap B)}{P(B)}$ was good though. To calculate $P(A\cap B)$ you could also just look at the things that satisfy $B: (2,4),(3,3),(3,4),(4,2),(4,3),(4,4)$, and see what fraction of them also satisfy $A$.

Comment: Good enough. That means, if P(A∩B) = 1/8, and P(B)=1/4, then P(A/B) = 1/4 or 0,25? And the P(B/A) will be, P(B∩A) = 14/16 = 7/8. P(A)=3/4, then P(B/A)=(14/16)/(3/4)? Is that correct answer?

Comment: Keep in mind that for $P(A),P(B),P(A\cap B)$ the set we're taking our options from is always the whole $16$. So for $A$, $4/16$ match and we have probability $4/16=1/4$. For $B$, $6/16$ match and we have probability $3/8$. For $P(A\cap B)$ (which is the same as $P(B\cap A), both of them just mean "which elements satisfy both of these at the same time") we have $2$ matching, which gives a probability of $2/16=1/8$. Go from there.

Comment: P(A/B) = 1/4, P(B/A) = 1/2
Is that correct?